# dotnet core development symlink

Tags: asp.net, azure, .net-core

I'm working on a dotnet project where the stylesheet is developed in a separate repository from the rest of the site. In order to use the stylesheet I have to compile with npm and then manually copy/paste the minified css file from it's repository into wwwroot (within the dotnet application). This is a very tedious development process which in theory could be resolved by using symlinks, but since I'm not a dotnet developer I have no idea how to do that and get it working with azure deployment pipeline.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Rather than symlinks, I'd consider producing a nuget package in the styles repository and linking that via a nuget feed into the code repository.